# Extracting text from online PDF and sorting through it

Tags: javascript, pdf.js

I'm trying to make a database of all the answers from a history competition so our team knows what to study for. This is an example pdf I'm trying to extract text data from: https://usa.iacompetitions.com/wp-content/uploads/sites/5/2023/08/2021-2022-HS-History-Bowl-Round-1-A-Set.pdf

I'd like to search for everything with "ANSWER: " and just take the text directly after it. Right now, this is my code, but I'm pretty inexperienced and I'm not sure how to continue:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://npmcdn.com/pdfjs-dist/build/pdf.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <input id="pdffile" name="pdffile" type="file" />
        <button id="btn" onclick="convert()">Process</button>
        <div id="result"></div>
    </body>
</html>

<script>

    function convert() {
        var fr=new FileReader();
        var pdff = new Pdf2TextClass();
        fr.onload=function(){
            pdff.pdfToText(fr.result, null, (text) => { document.getElementById('result').innerText += text; 
          for(var i = 0; i < text.length; i++) {
            
              var indicees = text.indexOf("ANSWER: ", i);
              console.log(text[indicees+8])
          }
                                                      });
        }
        fr.readAsDataURL(document.getElementById('pdffile').files[0])
        
    }

    function Pdf2TextClass() {
        var self = this;
        this.complete = 0;

        this.pdfToText = function (data, callbackPageDone, callbackAllDone) {
            console.assert(data instanceof ArrayBuffer || typeof data == 'string');
            var loadingTask = pdfjsLib.getDocument(data);
            loadingTask.promise.then(function (pdf) {


                var total = pdf._pdfInfo.numPages;
                //callbackPageDone( 0, total );        
                var layers = {};
                for (i = 1; i <= total; i++) {
                    pdf.getPage(i).then(function (page) {
                        var n = page.pageNumber;
                        page.getTextContent().then(function (textContent) {

                            //console.log(textContent.items[0]);0
                            if (null != textContent.items) {
                                var page_text = "";
                                var last_block = null;
                                for (var k = 0; k < textContent.items.length; k++) {
                                    var block = textContent.items[k];
                                    if (last_block != null && last_block.str[last_block.str.length - 1] != ' ') {
                                        if (block.x < last_block.x)
                                            page_text += "\r\n";
                                        else if (last_block.y != block.y && (last_block.str.match(/^(\s?[a-zA-Z])$|^(.+\s[a-zA-Z])$/) == null))
                                            page_text += ' ';
                                    }
                                    page_text += block.str;
                                    last_block = block;
                                }

                                textContent != null && console.log("page " + n + " finished."); //" content: \n" + page_text);
                                layers[n] = page_text + "\n\n";
                            }
                            ++self.complete;
                            //callbackPageDone( self.complete, total );
                            if (self.complete == total) {
                                window.setTimeout(function () {
                                    var full_text = "";
                                    var num_pages = Object.keys(layers).length;
                                    for (var j = 1; j <= num_pages; j++)
                                        full_text += layers[j];
                                    callbackAllDone(full_text);
                                }, 1000);
                            }
                        }); // end  of page.getTextContent().then
                    }); // end of page.then
                } // of for
            });
        }; // end of pdfToText()
    }; // end of class

</script>
```

At the end of this code, my goal is to count the number of times certain answer choices appear and format this somehow on the website or in an excel document.

Answer (score 0):

To get  single lines of text (Most PDF lines are only single without wrapping) you first need to fetch the PDF to your processor via HTTPS. Then in your second line of code you need to filter on your keyword that is in every target line and save for more code to parse.

Cross platform we can use Curl and Poppler Utils.

[image]

So for a Windows device it would be something like this

```
curl -o 1Aset.pdf https://usa.iacompetitions.com/wp-content/uploads/sites/5/2023/08/2021-2022-HS-History-Bowl-Round-1-A-Set.pdf
pdftotext -nopgbrk -enc UTF-8 1Aset.pdf -|find /i "answer:" >>answers.txt
```

Once you have the remote text saved as answers.txt you can then load and use in any suitable analysis language.

Note, that due to PDF writers discarding line feeds, they need to be re-inserted by extractors such as PDFtotext and then you may not get all the data you might have expected. In such cases by the time you have checked, it would be simpler to copy and paste the missing few at EOL (end of line).